# vector table address in mpcXXXX microcontrollers

Tags: firmware, embedded, powerpc

I'm disassembling some mpcXXXX microcontroller firmware, and I'm trying to find the vector table and the reset interrupt.

For example, I know that in ARM, in some of the microcontrollers, the vector table is stored in 0x0 address, and the reset ISR is pointed as the first entry of the vector table, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Does anyone know how to find the similar in PPC microcontrollers? I went through the documentation and references, but couldn't find the answer. I suspect it could also be at 0x0 offset, however, the first memory segment in IDA starts at 0x20000 in my case.

Comment: Which specific mpc you’re working with?

Comment: MPC5668G (probably)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the e200z650 core reference manual. The location of vector table can be configured from software in PPC architecture in the Interrupt Vector Prefix Register (IVPR).